# How to display Data on UITableView via NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I try to use a `NSMutableArray` object as data container to store the data.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* allTweets;
```

I grab the JSON from networking and parse it into `allTweets`. However I cannot reloadData with
`[self.tableView reloadData];` I receive `SIGABRT` on `main.m`

I try use `strong` in property. It crash again. When I use `weak`, no more crash happen. But the allTweets is always nil.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        //* other codes *//
        self.allTweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:50];
        [self getTimeline:nil];
    }

-(void) parseTweetJSON:(NSData*) responseData
{
    NSMutableArray* tempTweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
   //convert each element in array into nsdictionary
    for (NSDictionary *aTweet in tempTweets)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ (by @%@)", [aTweet objectForKey:@"text"], [[aTweet objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"]);
        Tweet* theTweet = [[Tweet alloc]init];    

        theTweet.text = [aTweet valueForKey:@"text"];
        theTweet.screenName = [[aTweet valueForKey:@"user"] valueForKey:@"screen_name"];
        theTweet.createAt = [aTweet valueForKey:@"create_at"];

        NSLog(@"class is %@", [[aTweet valueForKey:@"text"]class]);
        [allTweets addObject:theTweet];
    }

    if([allTweets count]>0)
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    Tweet* aTweet = [[Tweet alloc]init];
    aTweet = [allTweets objectAtIndex:row];

    cell.textLabel.text = aTweet.screenName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = aTweet.text;

    return cell;
}
```

What property type should I use for `NSMutableArray`,retain,copy,strong.
BTW I use Xcode 4.2

> 2011-11-28 02:54:23.968 SparkTweet[2039:10703] class is __NSCFString
>   2011-11-28 02:54:23.969 SparkTweet[2039:10703] -[Tweet
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e46c50
>   2011-11-28 02:54:23.970 SparkTweet[2039:10703] *** Terminating app due
>
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tweet
>
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6e46c50'
>
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x14c1052 0x189dd0a 0x14c2ced 0x1427f00 0x1427ce2 0x1b168f   0x4edf 0x24e548 0x250722 0x1007c7 0x1002c1 0x4371
>   0x14c2e72 0x98b9ef 0x149597f 0x13f8c39 0x13f8454 0x13f7db4 0x13f7ccb
>   0x1f8f879 0x1f8f93e 0x73a9b 0x2bf8 0x2b55 0x1) terminate called
>   throwing an exception

This exception thrown at `reloadData`. The NSLog print 20 recent tweets.

here is my tweet class declare

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Tweet : NSObject
{
    NSString* name;
    NSString* screenName;
    NSString* text;
    NSString* createAt;
}

@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* name;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* screenName;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* text;
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* createAt;

@end
```

Comment: are you confident, that parseTweetJSON: is called after viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Denis YES, I just update my viewDidload method. Can you have look?

Comment: What is printed on the console when you run it? Your calls to NSLog inside `parseTweetJSON` may give some hints about where the problem is. Besides that, if you set your `allTweets` property with `retain` you should initialize it with `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50]`

Comment: @LuizCarlosQuerinoFilho NSLog works. It print all recent correct tweets.

Comment: What is calling parseTweetJSON?  viewDidLoad doesn't call it ...

Comment: `parseTweetJSON` is called by `getTimeline` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: any chance that's on a background thread/async?

Answer (score 0):

1. Most important is not what property attributes you use for allTweets array but how properties of Tweet are defined. If they are not `retain`, it will crash.
2. What's this?

   Tweet* aTweet = [[Tweet alloc]init];
   aTweet = [allTweets objectAtIndex:row];
3. You should add `autorelease` to `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and to `Tweet* theTweet = [[Tweet alloc]init]` in `parseTweetJSON:`

Comment: I am using Xcode 4.2 with Automatic Reference Counting, `release`,`autorelease` are not useable.

Comment: Then please clearly state that you use ARC in your question. The Xcode version is not in any way connected to ARC usage. In any case please show your Tweet class definition.

Comment: Looks good. I can't find the problem. However I think everything is ok with your array. Your exception usually means that isEqualToString: was sent to string object that was deallocated. And now some other object, in your case Tweet, exists at the same address. So you need to find where string object could have been mistakenly deallocated.

Comment: I found the problem, `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` this delegates method crashed.

Comment: `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel * textDesc1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [textDesc1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    textDesc1.text=[self.allTweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [textDesc1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
    labelsize=[textDesc1.text sizeWithFont:textDesc1.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    labelsize.height=labelsize.height+35;
    return (CGFloat)labelsize.height; 
}`

Comment: Right, this line is wrong `textDesc1.text=[self.allTweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`. Next time please include all relevant source code in your question. Also you should use one of `sizeWithFont: ...` methods instead to measure strings.